# Any reason NOT to go whole hog in surface prep for installing earth-ground bonding clamps above ground outdoors?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding

**Background**

I'm tidying up the various *outdoor* bonding to earth ground in my 1960s era suburban Calif. house.  Bare copper wire, either 6 or 4 gauge, will connect them to the appropriate termination on the other end. Clamps and split bolts are all direct burial rated, but the pipe clamps will be exposed to rain etc.

There will be a number of bronze bonding clamps, appropriately sized:

1. Onto painted steel rigid gas pipe just on the house side of the meter.
2. Onto a 50-year old galvanized steel pipe length driven into the ground.
3. Onto buried 8 foot copper clad grounding rods.

I know that the GEC must be unbroken from rod to electrical box, but will be using split bolts to bond the gas pipe wire and an EGC from an outdoor outlet to the GEC along the way.

**Question**

What surface prep is best for these copper/bronze connections? I plan to sand the gas pipe and galvanized pipe to bare metal at the clamps and apply copper anti-ox paste between the sanded surface and the clamp. Similarly, I plan to apply a bit of copper anti-ox between wire and grounding rod and wires and split bolts. Should I apply a bit of anti-ox on the threads of the various clamping screws? Afterward, should I try to protect the pipe/clamp sanded areas from rusting by e.g. painting or wrapping with self-fusing rubber electrical tape?

*Photo of style of clamp to be used for pipes*
[image: Photo of style of clamp to be used for pipes]

*Photo of style of clamp to be used for grounding rods*
[image: Photo of style of clamp to be used for grounding rods]

*Photo of split bolt for wire/wire bonding*
[image: Photo of split bolt for wire/wire bonding]

Comment: Most code is the minimum requirement, so doing better than code is a good thing.

Comment: Yes - I'm just trying to figure out what's overkill in practice.

Comment: If the 50 year old pipe has been in the ground that long, I would forget about it, it is just rust now.  Overkill probably anything over double what code says.  Any bare metal(steel) should be protected, don't need gas pipes rusting and having pin holes near where there might be sparks.

Comment: @crip659 Yes, the gas pipe would be what I would be most concerned about. How exactly would you protect the sanded surface - paint over it with the clamp in place, use some kind of protective wrap (like the rubber self-fusing tape), something else?

Comment: I'm also worried about bonding to the pipe, galvanised is zinc plated, and zinc almost as bad as aluminium for bonding copper to.

Comment: I would recommend contacting the gas company to ensure that any work you do to the gas line meets their standards. I'm sure you'll get good recommendations here, but should anything fall short of their standards/codes and there were to be a problem, you'd be liable.